# Plot is not displaying when executing script

Tags: python, spyder

When I execute my script via command line `py planck.py` the plot is not displaying but when I use my Spyder IDE, the plot is able to display but I am not sure why it isn't showing via command line.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def BB_wl(wavel, temp):
    # wavel in micron
    c1=1.191042E8 # W/m2-sr-um4
    c2=1.4387752E4 # K mu
    value = c1 / (wavel**5*(np.exp(c2/(wavel*temp))+5.0E4))
    return value # in W/m2-sr-um

my_figure = figure(figsize=(10,4))
main_axes = my_figure.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
main2_axes = main_axes.twiny()
main2_axes.set_xlabel('Frequency [THz]',size="x-large")
main2_axes.set_xticklabels(["3000", "2257", "1515", "772", "30"])
small_ax  = my_figure.add_axes( [0.35, 0.5, 0.25, 0.3] )
main_axes.set_xlabel('Wavelength [micron]', size="x-large")
main_axes.set_ylabel(r'$[\mathrm{Wm^{-2} \, \mu m^{-1}}]$',size="x-large")
wave = np.linspace(1,10,1000)
spectral = BB_wl(wave, 1000)/100
main_axes.plot(wave, spectral, color="red", linewidth=3)
small_ax.plot(wave, spectral, color="blue", linewidth=3)
my_figure.show()
my_figure.savefig('planck.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the script runs till end.

Try to stop the script via

```
x = input("press key to exit")
```

add it to the end of the script.
in this case your script will wait and you will be able to see the figure. I hope this helps.